# Issue with html Geo location

Tags: android, html, geolocation

I've got some issue with geo location in html.

I'm developing a android app, one of the pages is webview this one loads a url I've been created.

The problem is: it ask to allow location but how to set it so always is allowed ??

Because that is not possible in Android app to request.

This is the code:

```html
<iframe id="map_iframe" style="border:none; margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%; height:150%;" src="https://url.com" allow="geolocation; microphone; camera; midi *; marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" border="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hey Dennis. Welcome to Stack Overflow. "This is the code:" is not followed by code. That code could help you get the answer. Please add it.

Comment: Hi, 
Yes the code is there :)

Comment: I edited it that's why now you see the code :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got some issue with geo location in html.

I'm developing an Android app, one of the pages is webview this one loads a url I've created.

The problem is: it ask to allow location but how to set it so always is allowed?

Because that is not possible in Android app to request.

This is the code:

style="border:none; margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%; height:150%;" src="https://url.com" allow="geolocation; microphone; camera; midi *; marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" border="0">

Comment: please delete this answer it is duplicated